# Regex to catch a name and multiple groups with the same pattern

Tags: regex

I have the following strings:

```
| Elencia   { 1: Simple one, 0: A longer sentence, or maybe not, 2: Another sentence }
| Elencia   { 10:    Sentence with spaces on left,     0: Same but with some spaces on right      }
```

I would like to catch the name on the left and the number + the sentence avoiding the multiple spaces on the left and the right.

I wrote this at the moment:

```
(?<point>[\d]+):\s+(?<content>[\w ]+)
```

but it only catches the part inside the curly brackets and it includes the spaces at the end, which is not what I want.

What I would like to have. First example:

```
- Elencia as name
- "1" as point, "Simple one" as sentence
- "0" as point, "A longer sentence, or maybe not" as sentence
- "2" as point, "Another sentence" as sentence
```

Second example:

```
- Elencia as name
- "10" as point, "Sentence with spaces on left" as sentence
- "0" as point, "Sentence with spaces on left" as sentence
```

I'm using the regex with [gdscript](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_regex.html) but PHP or JavaScript style would work too.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```sh
(?:(?<name>\w+)\s+{|(?!^)\G)\W*(?<point>\d+):\s+(?<content>.+?(?=,\s+\d+:|\s*}))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QEjMqV/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:`: Start a non-capture group

  - `(?<name>\w+)`: Match 1+ word characters in group named `name`
  - `\s+{`: Match 1+ whitespace followed by a `{`
  - `|`: OR
  - `(?!^)\G`: Start from end of the previous match
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `\W*`: Match 0+ non-word characters
- `(?<point>\d+)`: Match 1+ digits in names capture group `point`
- `:\s+`: Match a `:` followed by 1+ whitespace
- `(?<content>.+?(?=,\s+\d:|\s*})`:
- `(?=`: Start a positive lookahead assertion

  - `,\s+\d+:`: Match comma, 1+ whitespace, 1+ digits followed by `:`
  - `|`: OR
  - `\s*}`: Match 0+ whitespace followed by `}`
- `)`: End positive lookahead assertion

Comment: Oh I didn't know I can use the lookahead like this! If I may, I still need a little help to get the name on the left.

Comment: Yes, sure I watched. But "Elencia" is not captured, it was my meaning. Everything else is really good.

Comment: Are you doing this in php or Java?

Comment: In gdscript. In the documentation they said it's based on the PCRE2 library. If I'm correct, PHP is based on this library too.

Comment: ok try my updated answer

Comment: Awesome! That totally what I wanted! Thank you a lot!